# Using combinatorics to form words of some letters.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Original question:** How many "words" of 1 letter, 2 letters, 3 letters and 4 letters can be formed with the letters of "MAAS"

Both combinations and permutations are needed to solve this question, however I find it hard it to distinguish between the two.

I understand how to make words of 4 letters, but 1, 2 and 3 I find difficult. I can of course compute it by hand, since I only have 4 letters, but they specifically ask for permutations and combinations.

Anyone who can help  me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Consider the 2 $A$ letters to be distinct, what are the permutations of $MA_1A_2S$? Then, you should divide by how many times you overcount a specific word, for example $MA_1A_2S$ should be considered the same as $MA_2A_1S$.

Comment: That's a good HInt, as it nicely plays into the combinations and permutations separation!

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's take the case of $3$ letter words.

We can think of finding all $3$ letter words as a $2$-step process:

First, find all possible groups of $3$ letters. For example, we can decide to use both $A$'s and the single $M$

Second, now that we have decided what letters to use, we have to put them in some order to make an actual word. So, with the $3$ letters I picked before, I could make $AAM$, $AMA$, and $MAA$

The first step, where we do *not* care about the *order* of the letters, is about *combinations*. Think of it as creating a salad: what 'ingredients' do we want to put together?  What can we combine with what?

The second step, where we *do*  care about the *order* of the letters, is about *permutations*.